# Как правильно оформить редирект 301?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, .htaccess, apache, apache2

Есть сайт у которого более 10к страниц типа : /ru/pp/rubric/yyyy/mm/dd.html
необходимо сделать редирект на url типа: /arhiv/rubric/yyyy-mm-dd
Насколько я понимаю, целесообразно это делать в .htaccess. 
Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно сформулировать регулярное выражение для редиректа, или может быть какие нибудь другие варианты, как это можно провернуть.
P.S wordpress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В файле `.htaccess` сразу после

```
RewriteEngine On
```

добавляете новую строку с правилом

```
RewriteRule ^ru/pp/rubric/(\d{4})/(\d{2})/(\d{2}).html$ arhiv/rubric/$1-$2-$3 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

или

```
RewriteRule ^ru/pp/rubric/(\d{4})/(\d{2})/(\d{2}).html$ arhiv/rubric/$1-$2-$3? [R=301,L]
```

если get параметры передавать при редиректе не нужно.